# How can I get the filesize of an image with an image style programmatically

Tags: media

I need to make two links for an image, one link points to a low res version the other to the original file.

I'm creating the link for the low res with image_style_url

```
<?php print image_style_url('img-lib', $data->field_field_photo[0]['raw']['uri']) ?>
```

How can I print out the filesize of the image with `img-lib` style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the size of the original image easily:

```
$size = filesize($data->field_field_photo[0]['raw']['uri']);
```

But the size of an image file behind a derivative path is impossible to get reliably. The files aren't generated until the URL is first visited, so the file may simply not exist yet.

For those that *do* already exist, you can use [`image_style_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_style_path/7):

```
$path = image_style_path('img-lib', $data->field_field_photo[0]['raw']['uri']);
if (file_exists($path)) {
  $size = filesize($path);
}
```

If it's 'mission-critical' to get the file size, you can always force-create the derivative there and then with [`image_style_create_derivative()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_create_derivative/7):

```
$path = image_style_path('img-lib', $data->field_field_photo[0]['raw']['uri']);
if (file_exists($path)) {
  $size = filesize($path);
}
else {
  if (image_style_create_derivative('img-lib', $data->field_field_photo[0]['raw']['uri'], $path) === TRUE) {
    $size = filesize($path);
  }
}

if (!isset($size)) {
  // Something went wrong creating the derivative...
}
```

It's worth noting that you shouldn't do all (or any really) of the above directly in a template file. Instead, move your logic out to a [preprocess function](https://drupal.org/node/223430) and pass variables in.

And if you're looking for full-on 'best practice', instead of accessing the field data directly through the array (e.g. `$data->field_field_photo[0]['raw']['uri']`), prefer [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) for procedural-style, or an [`EntityMetadataWrapper`](https://drupal.org/node/1021556) if you're comfortable with OO.